# angular datepicker bootstrap-ui doesent work in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I use Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Problem is that inside view datepicker won't work correctly.
so in view I have code below:

```
<input type="text" 
       datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
       ng-model="datepicker"
       show-weeks="fasle" 
       is-open="opened"
 />
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
```

in controller I try to show date picker by clicking on button:

```
scope.open = function(){
   timeout(function() {
    scope.opened = true;
   });
};
```

in **scope.opened store true!** but nothing happend;

Second problem I try to retrieve date from date picker. When I initialize it I use next:

```
scope.datepicker = new Date();
scope.format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

and retrieve

```
scope.save = function() {
 console.log(scope.datepicker);
};
```

date picker always return current date...

### BUT out side view everything works perfect! Why?

EDIT

this is live [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/srxWpW6WZPbCZuKCiJqm?p=preview)

Try to change date and click save. OR try to call dapicker clicking by button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add controller to `routeProvider`:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'template.html',
                controller: 'DatepickerDemoCtrl'
            })
    });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L2jC12qTHr0HOagprScE?p=preview)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" 
          datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
          ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" 
          min="minDate"
          max="'2015-06-22'" 
          datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
          date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
          ng-required="true"
          />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;
  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };



  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.opened = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };
};
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but in my case I work with gn-view. and load template using routing.

Comment: add live demo to bottom of my question

Comment: add controller to routeProvider, fixed your Plunker and edit my answer

Comment: this sounds like a solution. But, in this case controller will be loaded twice. http://plnkr.co/edit/4t72GWWszIBCtzwJzQYj. Best solution is to seperate logic in deffrent files? load controller only in config of router, no in header of html? P.S. But without additing controller to route I have access to scope of this controller why?